# How do I prevent the default Cut event for a JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, keystroke

What I'm trying to do is to prevent Cut/Copy/Paste on a JTree, because I want all node-moving to be done via drag and drop.

Copy and Paste are already prevented in the canImport and importData methods of the handler, but I can't think how to prevent Cut.

In addition, all these didn't work:

```
Tree.getActionMap().put( "cut", null );

InputMap inputMap = Tree.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('X', java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK), null);

ActionMap actionMap = Tree.getActionMap();
actionMap.put("cut", null);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @user1953221 this is one of parameters for DND, read Oracles DND tutorial (there is example about JList or JTree???)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/listpaste.html This tutorial uses actionMap.put() to set the binding for "cut" action. I tried the same but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
ActionMap actionMap = tree.getActionMap();
actionMap.remove("cut");
actionMap.getParent().remove("cut");
actionMap.remove("copy");
actionMap.getParent().remove("copy");
actionMap.remove("paste");
actionMap.getParent().remove("paste");
```